# Tratamento de string - como separar número decimal de texto na string?

Tags: php, html5

O algoritmo abaixo da um ping no host e faz todo o tratamento até pegar a parte específica que eu quero que é o valor da taxa do ping

```
<?php
$host = 'www.google.com.br';
$execPing = shell_exec('ping -c 1 ' . $host);
$vetExpl = explode("\n", $execPing);
$locStr = array_keys(preg_grep('/icmp_seq/', $vetExpl))[0];
$dadosVet = array_slice($vetExpl, $locStr, -5);
foreach ($dadosVet as $vetLinha) {
  $strVetor = explode(' ', $vetLinha);
  $tempo = preg_grep('/time=/', $strVetor);
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($tempo);
}
?>
```

O que acontece é que a variável `$tempo`, que contem o valor da taxa, imprime parte texto e parte número. ex abaixo:

```
array(1) {
  [7]=>
  string(9) "time=69.7"
}
```

O que quero é pegar somente os números com o decimal, neste caso o `69.7`

Testei com diversos exemplos e não consigo separar o número decimal do texto

---

Não posso usar indice, a posição muda conforme muda o endereço IP
usando o endereço www google com br, ele me traz a taxa na posição 7
usando endereço dentro da rede, ele me traz a taxa na posição 6

Comment: Se todas as strings tiverem esse formato, você pode fazer 1 implode, ficaria
`$time = implode("=", $tempo);` e para acessar ficaria `$time[1]`

Comment: @PauloVictor não seria `explode`?

Comment: Sim, o correto de fato é explode, ficaria `$time = explode("=", $tempo);`, desculpe, fiz correndo.

Comment: Já tinha feito assim. Continua dando NULL

Comment: Pode mostrar o resultado de $strVetor?

Comment: Tente `$time = explode("=", $tempo[7]);`

Comment: array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "64"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "bytes"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "from"
  [3]=>
  string(24) "eze03s06-in-f3.1e100.net"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "(172.217.29.3):"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "icmp_seq=1"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "ttl=39"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "time=63.0"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "ms"
}

Comment: com "$time = explode("=", $tempo[7]);" também não funciona, pois dependendo do número IP pode mudar a posição da string no array
exe: se uso 'localhost' a posição no array passa a ser 6

Comment: Andrei, coloca um exemplo de entrada e um da saída esperada... vai ficar mais fácil de te ajudarem.

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar a função explode conforme abaixo.
Note que foi retornado um array, portanto você sabe a posição que precisa recuperar.
Espero ter ajudado.

```
<?php
$host = '192.168.0.24';
$execPing = shell_exec('ping -c 1 ' . $host);
$vetExpl = explode("\n", $execPing);
$locStr = array_keys(preg_grep('/icmp_seq/', $vetExpl))[0];
$dadosVet = array_slice($vetExpl, $locStr, -5);
foreach ($dadosVet as $vetLinha) {
  $strVetor = explode(' ', $vetLinha);
  for($i=0; $i<sizeof($strVetor); $i++){
     if(preg_match("/time/", $strVetor[$i])){
        $tempo = explode("time=", $strVetor[6]);
        echo "\n";
        echo "Tempo: " . $tempo[1];
        echo "\n";
        echo " ";
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Resultado:

> root@79bbb258c614:/var/www/teste# php lala.php
>
> Tempo: 0.869
>   root@79bbb258c614:/var/www/teste#

Pode haver uma diferença no índice do seu array, isso dependendo da versão do teu ping. Então, testa o índice e você conseguirá achar certinho.
dê um var_dump no $strVetor e veja o índice que precisa.

Comment: Não funcionou. Estou rodando no debian

Comment: Realizei o teste antes e deu certinho... Consegue enviar o erro que deu?

Comment: <?php
$host = '192.168.0.24';
$execPing = shell_exec('ping -c 1 ' . $host);
$vetExpl = explode("\n", $execPing);
$locStr = array_keys(preg_grep('/icmp_seq/', $vetExpl))[0];
$dadosVet = array_slice($vetExpl, $locStr, -5);
foreach ($dadosVet as $vetLinha) {
  $strVetor = explode(' ', $vetLinha);
  $tempo = explode("time=", $strVetor[6]);

  echo "<pre>";
  echo "\n";
  echo "Tempo: " . $tempo[1];
  echo "\n";
  echo " ";


}
?> Resultado: root@79bbb258c614:/var/www/teste# php lala.php
<pre>
Tempo: 1.03

Comment: aqui aparece NULL

Comment: Então, faça como comentei ali na resposta (editei ela). Dê um var_dump no $strVetor e veja qual é o índice que você tem que usar.

Comment: ele muda conforme muda o endereço IP que uso
usar 192.168.0.1 ou 10.117.10.100 é diferente de usar localhost ou endereço de sites
conforme muda o IP muda o indice que vou precisar

Comment: Cara, é simples.. basta você testar se no índice corrente, existe o tempo, e imprimir :)

Comment: Editei novamente com o ajuste que você precisa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91872/discussion-between-filipe-l-constante-and-andrei).

Answer (score 0):

Assim funciona

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$execPing = shell_exec('ping -c 1 ' . $host);
$vetExpl = explode("\n", $execPing);
$locStr = array_keys(preg_grep('/time=/', $vetExpl))[0];
$dadosVet = array_slice($vetExpl, $locStr, -5);
foreach ($dadosVet as $vetLinha) {
  $strVetor = explode(' ', $vetLinha);
  $tempo = preg_grep('/time=/', $strVetor);
  $str = implode('',$tempo);
  $taxa = substr($str, 5);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tempo);
print_r($taxa);
?>
```